# Filling NULL values with previous NON-NULL values in SQL (Athena)

Tags: sql, null, amazon-athena, lag

I have the following example table (I am using AWS Athena):

[image]

I want to add in a new/overwrite current Session field so the NULLs will be filled with the previous NON NULL value. Result table should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`coalesce`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce) on current value and result of [`lag`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) window function with `ignore nulls` option:

```sql
WITH dataset( date, event, value) AS (
    values 
        (date '2021-07-24', 'a', null),
        (date '2021-07-25', 'b', 4),
        (date '2021-07-26', 'c', null),
        (date '2021-07-27', 'c', 5),
        (date '2021-07-28', 'a', null),
        (date '2021-07-29', 'b', null)
)

SELECT date,
    event,
    coalesce(
        value,
        lag(value) ignore nulls over(order by date)
    ) value
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| date | event | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-24 | a |  |
| 2021-07-25 | b | 4 |
| 2021-07-26 | c | 4 |
| 2021-07-27 | c | 5 |
| 2021-07-28 | a | 5 |
| 2021-07-29 | b | 5 |